# Handle data from POST requests in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request

Let's say I have in my code:

```
$.post("addUser.js", { "name": "John" })
```

What should I put in this `addUser.js` file to handle the post request?

```
whenIReceivePOSTRequest((data) => console.log(data))
```

Comment: You'd be better off using a node router and making a small REST endpoint to do this. [Here's](https://medium.com/@onejohi/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-nodejs-and-express-da6273ed7ca9) a good example you can follow along to

Comment: Hmm, this tutorial explains how to create a file? Or I don't understand it

Comment: can you clarify what you want to achieve? It's not very clear what you want, handle request on server side or just client side by making request to server side

Comment: I want that when the client does a POST request on addUsers.js file, it logs the data the client gave in the POST request